# BuildRoot errors doing make [package/pkg-generic.mk:293:

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, buildroot

When I do make of buildroot appears this error

> ```
> make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:293: /home/vitor/buildroots/buildroot/output/build/host-gcc-final-11.3.0/.stamp_built]
> ```
>
> Error 2

Does anyone know the solution?
Thanks already for the time

Note: The first time I have do buildroot it worked fine, but for an work I needed to change some files and since that stop working, so I deleted that buildroot and tried to do a new ones and always appear this error.

Comment: Please [use the mailing list](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#community-resources) for getting help. Also, the actual error is somewhere above the piece you posted here. Look for `***` in the output and copy a few lines above that.

Answer (score 0):

Recommandation: don't use the current "master" of Buildroot if you're new to Buildroot, but instead use a release tag. As Arnout said, you did not post enough lines of the error to really know, but based on the package that failed I suspect you're encountering one of the issues we've had with the update of glibc to version 2.36, which is not yet part of any Buildroot stable release.

Use Buildroot 2022.02 or 2022.08, but not Buildroot master if you're interested in having something that "works" :-)